# How to ensure text fits within area

Tags: android, surfaceview, paint, font-size

I have a `SurfaceView` where I'm drawing a matrix (game board) and each cell of the matrix is 40 pixels in height and width.

Within those cells, I have to store a Scrabble-like tile along the lines of:

```
+---------+
|    #    |
|   # #   |
|  #   #  |
|  #####  |
|  #   #  |
|       17|
+---------+
```

The letter is always a single letter and the number is always a number, at most two digits.

In order to do this I actually have calculated the position of the top-left pixel of the cell on my surface, and what I want to do is to draw the letter and the number to certain specifications.

I need to ensure that the number fits in a given region (say the bottom right 10x10 cells) and that the letter is centered in the tile without encroaching on the number region.

I currently plan on using the `Paint.getTextBounds()` to figure out the size of the largest letter and number and, if it turned out the size was too big, I'd simply do it in a smaller font.

I am, of course, open to suggestions for a better way. Even if there *is* no better way, I still have a problem.

The way I'm setting up the paint object is with:

```
numPaint = new Paint();
numPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
numPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

and the actual drawing of the text is simply:

```
canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(num), pixcol + 30, pixrow + 30, numPaint);
```

That *does* place the number in the bottom right hand corner of the cell as expected but at no point have I specified a font size or anything else that's likely to stop the text from going outside the cell if, for example, it ends up being 15x15 in size.

It appears to fit through sheer luck. In any case, I've set up the `alphaPaint` object exactly the same way but I want it to be a little bigger.

Sorry for meandering, I just wanted to ensure all the details were there. Bottom line question is: how do we set the font size of a paint object? The object has a `getFontMetrics()` but doesn't appear to have the `set...` equivalent. The `setTypeface()` looked initially promising but that the font and bold/italic/etc, with no mention of forcing a specific size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set font size use `numPaint.setTextSize()`. Here is a link to the documentation [`public void setTextSize (float textSize)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextSize%28float%29)

Comment: Oh, you're kidding me! How the blazes did I not see that??? It's right there about ten lines above the typeface stuff. How embarrassment?